# Message becomes unreadable after setting string property (IBM MQ)

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am trying to send MQ message from .NET application using amqmdnet library.
I put to queue simple message with two string properties like that:

```cs
var message = new MQMessage();
message.SetStringProperty("MessageID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
message.SetStringProperty("DocType", docTypeVal);
    
foreach (var b in content)
{
    message.WriteByte(b);
}
                    
var o = new MQPutMessageOptions();
var q = IBM_mqm.AccessQueue(ConnectionOptions.QueueNameOutput, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT 
    +  MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
q.Put(message, o);
q.Close();
```

It works perfect when property "DocType" contains only latin symbols, digits and other general symbols.

```cs
message.SetStringProperty("DocType", "SomeEngText");
```

[image: In the MQ Explorer it looks like that]

But when the property contains cyrillic symbols the message becomes unreadable. It's format becomes MQRFH2 despite the fact that I never set it. And named properties are empty.

```cs
message.SetStringProperty("DocType", "Договор купли продажи ТС");
```

[image: That's what happen in MQ Explorer when message contains cyrillic property]
When I am trying to read this message from my client an error 6106 MQRC_ENCODING_ERROR comes.

Some cyrillic values works fine (for example, "Кредитный договор"), but most of them breaks the message.

I tried to specify CCSID of the message like that:

```
message.CharacterSet = MQC.CODESET_UTF;
```

And also to set format:

```
message.Format = MQC.MQFMT_NONE;
```

But it didn't help.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you correctly identifying the code page that your Cyrillic characters are in? Perhaps you can update your question with the codepage you are using and some of the code points that cause issues - that is the character and it's hex value.

Comment: CCSID of queue manager is 1208. I've tired to specify character set of the message in the code (message.CharacterSet = MQC.CODESET_UTF;) and unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: This isn't an ASCII/EBCDIC confusion, is it?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Please can you also update your question with some of the code points that cause issues - that is the character and its hex value.